# How to install ubuntu server 14.04 without internet connection?

Tags: server

Ubuntu Server 14.04 installation fails without internet connection. Also, tried the minimal installation using F4 function key in the starting by choosing minimal install. In this case also, it is asking for internet connection.

Comment: Seems like nobody knows

Comment: I'm also with the same problem. I need to do a minimal installation because it's not detecting my network config.

Answer (score 0):

It seems ridiculous to me that a 14.04(.1) server install requires an available HTTP APT repository server. I could find no simple way of getting it to install without one.

As it happened I had a 12.04 server set up with CNTLM (to authenticate properly with the corporation's main proxy) and squid-deb-proxy (for package caching) and by setting this as the proxy during installation it would get through but this is a real pain as I wanted a clean offline install which I then pointed **just** apt at the squid-deb-proxy (i.e. `Acquire::http::Proxy ...`).

The only reason this server should ever be attempting to connect to the outside world is for critical system updates so configuring the whole system to use that proxy (which won't allow connection to anything other than Ubuntu update servers anyway) seems silly.

I'll try to update this once I know all the places that the installer saves proxy details entered during installation so they can be removed post-install. Doing it the way I have done above at least ensures the password for proxy authentication doesn't get saved in any weird, unknown places.

Comment: They need to have an option to access the repository via local connected harddisk. I had the server install disk and a copy of the entire repository. That is not enough. You need to two computers, one to run ubuntu desktop, so you can serve the repository on http, and another to run the server setup and connect to it.

Comment: That's not correct. If you have a copy of all the files it is possible to configure a directory as a local repository. I don't know how off the top of my head but that's how the Ubuntu installation ISOs work. My question refers to a way in which you can confuse the installation so that it gets stuck in a loop of needing a remote repository, even though there is one on the DVD that was used to run the currently executing installation.